# Looking for Headset to 2-in-1 adapter

Tags: audio, microphone, adapter, headphones

I'm looking for an adapter that lets me connect my Headset (1 headphone connector, 1 microphone connector) to my laptop, which has headphone/microphone combination connector, like it can be found on the iPhone. I can find connectors that lets you split audio in two for two headphones, but I can't find a headphone/microphone combination adapter. What product name should I be looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would start by looking at [Headset Buddy](http://www.theheadsetbuddy.com/), you may find cheaper by searching based on some of the terms found on the website. But they certainly seem to specialize in this type of product.

Comment: Thanks. I was rather looking for an European Seller, but it's good to know an alternative if I don't find anything in Europe. Still, I can't find anything when searching for similar product names in local web shops

Comment: Apparently I won't find anything else. Thanks for that reply.

Comment: To me it seems like any decent shop has what your looking for. But if you want the opposite of what you want - that is you have a single cord headset which you want to use on your computer with separate microphone and headset connections - then you'll definitely find this site interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I was looking for the same thing and as far as I can tell found what you (and I) were looking for:

[3.5mm 4 Position to 2x 3 Position 3.5mm Headset Splitter Adapter - M/F](http://uk.startech.com/Cables/Audio-Video/Audio-Cables/35mm-4-Position-to-2x-3-Position-35mm-Headset-Splitter-Adapter-Male-to-Female~MUYHSMFF)

I have no idea how long the above link will work, but their product name should give some hint at what you need to look for.